# Overriding Relation Remote Method In Strongloop Loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a User model and a Follower model which has HasManyThrough relation with User for the follower and followee.
How can I change the default __get__followers method parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that I can juse add a new remote method the normal way.

```
loopback.remoteMethod(
            UserModel.prototype.getFollows,
            {
                description: 'Get the users who are followed by the user',
                accepts: [
                    {arg: 'page', type: 'Number', http: {source: 'query'}, required: true}
                ],
                returns: {arg: 'data', type: 'object'},
                http: {verb: 'get', path: '/follows'},
                isStatic: false,
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way. Tree hasMany Leaves and we want to override the `__get__leaves` relation handler of a Tree.

```
/**
 * Before Remote handler
 *
 * @param {Object} ctx - Context
 * @param {Function} next - Callback function
 */
Tree.beforeRemote('**', function (ctx, unused, next) {
  if (ctx.method.name === '__get__leaves') {
    return Tree.getLeaves(ctx)
  }

  next()
})

/**
 * Override Relation handler
 *
 * @param {Object} ctx - Context
 */
Tree.getLeaves = (ctx) => {
  ctx.res.sendStatus(200)
}
```